# One-click download for Phonegap app?

Tags: android, iphone, cordova

I have created my first Phonegap app, and it rocks. However, it would be nice to be able to give a link for iPhone and Android users, so they  can literally just click on it and it will give them the option to download and install the app. Is there a way to do this for iphone and android?

I know the build.phonegap.com offers a method, but it requires going to their site. i was hoping I could just upload the  APK file or whatever the apple equivalent is, and people can easily install the app using my link (i.e. without the apple store and chrome store).

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not overly familiar with the process for iOS, but for android: yes, but the download link is unlikely to work for the average user.

Licenced Android devices, by default, do not allow installation of APKs from unknown sources (for most normal users, this means APKs which have not been downloaded from the Play store).

For a user to install an APK downloaded from [anywhere other than the Play Store], they must enable the **Unknown Sources** option in **Settings > Security** on their Android device.

However, if the users you are distributing to are willing to do this, then you can upload your APK to any online storage space which will allow it and just provide the download link (i.e. the direct share link from a Drive or DropBox account, as example).

Once the file has finished downloading, the user can click on the "download complete" notification on their device and the APK installer will launch (as is the case when you scan a QR code on the Phonegap build service). If you want use QR codes yourself, instead of links, just encode your download link as a QR code (many online services available).

See: https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/open-distribution.html

Comment: The user will need a QR code scanner (any QR code scanner) on their device. Again, just like the PG build service. In that sense, just providing a link would be one less requirement.